# Building an inbuilt wardrobe based on PAX - how do I finish?

Tags: finishing

I have an Ikea PAX frame that I am using MDF to make look inbuilt by building a fake wall to enclose the frame.

My questions are about what materials I should be using to fill in:

1. the screw holes?
2. the gaps between the frame and MDF?
3. the gaps between the MDF and wall? (if different)
4. the gaps between the different pieces wood in my fake wall.

I'm going to prime and paint the MDF, how do you recommend I get a consistent finish with the PAX frame...inevitably some of the finishing product will end up on this frame. Do I sand the entire frame and paint that too?

[image]

Comment: Next time, instead of raw mdf, try to source melamine particleboard in a color as similar to the pax as possible. Nail it (preferably with a pneumatic gun) instead of screw it. This time, mask off the pax with tape to avoid getting finish on it. Do not under any circumstances, sand the pax.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are using the mdf in place of what would usually be drywall as a wall covering. Any screw or nail holes in the mdf or the door frame (jamb) can be spackled and sanded and then primed and painted. If the joint between the mdf and the existing wall is minimal then you can just use latex caulking to fill it.

Typically the joint between the door frame (door jamb) and the mdf (wall covering) would be covered with a door trim (door casing).

All of this (for painting) would have the screw or nail holes filled and all the joints caulked and then sanded and primed and painted.

Comment: More of a gap between the MDF and the PAX frame than the wall. Should I caulk between the PAX frame and the MDF also or is there something better I could do? I still have the PAX doors to put on aswell so perhaps they will cover the gap there?